# Facebook me/invitable_friends, return link on small picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Picture url for not app friend: `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/c0.3.631.631/s50x50/1796710_1380751512198760_2043305802_n.jpg?oh=7e5cde9326c5bedd0416bf091b198b75&oe=55247955&__gda__=1433029165_feddf79888157b002c65970ea505c266`
Picture size will be 50x50,

Can I somehow get bigger image than the one API returns in picture.data.url ?
Or can I get a normal id for not app friends?

(me/invitable_friends return id such sAVkqWm2Ns53i0og7xtBcGzDkBxJ7sKTO7sUaC_e1A3uDxeTZLyV08E6slPz4H64VeqQA5SpxBtA7un8CQXgZXqHpi_1fEwTKlWd7RVZWrtoILA)

for using `http://graph.facebook.com/"ID"/picture?type=large`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

me/invitable_friends?fields=picture.width(320).height(320)

Answer (score 0):

on iPhone you can do it like this

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/taggable_friends"
                             parameters:@{@"fields" : @"name,picture.width(500).height(500)"}
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                  /* handle the result */
                  /* returns a list of friends with links to bigger pictures */
                      }];
```

the key there is `parameters`